# Python transform current list into 2d

Tags: python, list

I have designed a code which functions as I wish to do, by asking the administrator at my private school the number of students, how many grades to input per each student and lastly the course code for the courses that they are taking.

```
COLS= int(input("number of students to enter: "))
ROWS= int(input("number of grades per student: "))


def main(COLS,ROWS):
    number =[]


    for c in range(COLS):
        student =(input("enter student Name: "))
        number.append(student)

        for r in range (ROWS):
            course=input("Enter course Code: ")
            number.append(course)
            grades =(input("Enter grade for module: "))
            number.append(grades)

    print(number)

main(COLS,ROWS)
```

An example of the output is:

```
number of students to enter: 3
number of grades per student: 2
enter student Name: LarryH
Enter course Code: Math202
Enter grade for module: 80
Enter course Code: Sci101
Enter grade for module: 90
enter student Name: JeromeK
Enter course Code: TT101
Enter grade for module: 60
Enter course Code: PSY205
Enter grade for module: 50
enter student Name: CheungL
Enter course Code: PS100
Enter grade for module: 80
Enter course Code: Math300
Enter grade for module: 50
['LarryH', 'Math202', '80', 'Sci101', '90', 'JeromeK', 'TT101', '60', 'PSY205', '50', 'CheungL', 'PS100', '80', 'Math300', '50']
```

Now the code works except for the last line of my output where the list is given with the students and their respective grades and course code.

I am trying to instead of my output producing that 1d list, produce a 2d list, for example:

```
[
   ["Andre", "MA22", 79, "MA300", 88, "CM202", 69],
   ["Larry", "PS44", 67, "MA555", 80, "ACC200", 67], 
   ...
  ]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I may alter in my code to produce a desired output like that above,

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the first loop, you can create a new temporary array to store the data for that particular student, e.g.:

```
for c in range(COLS):
    studentInfo = [] # Info per-student
    student =(input("enter student Name: "))
    studentInfo.append(student)

    for r in range (ROWS):
        course=input("Enter course Code: ")
        studentInfo.append(course)
        # ...
        # ...

    number.append(studentInfo)
```

You could also look into storing student info in dictionaries, rather than lists so that the order is not as important. So instead of:

```
singleStudentInfo = ["Andre", "MA22", 79, "MA300", 88, "CM202", 69]
```

You would have:

```
singleStudentInfo = {"name": "Andre", "MA22": 79, "MA300": 88, "CM202": 69}
```

Comment: I've modified my answer slightly for you. You need to append all the student information to this temporary array _studentInfo_, then at the end of the for c in range(COLS): loop, capped the studentInfo to the number array.

Comment: Awesome work,  basically the idea was to create a list within the list